# How to convert logical conditions to a variable of a function

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I would like to achieve the above for the following:

```
Rn = 0.009; % Resolution of simulation (in m^3)
Xs = -1 : Rn : 1;
Ys = -1 : Rn : 1;
Zs =  0 : Rn : 1; 

[X Y Z] = meshgrid(Xs, Ys, Zs); 
alpha   = atan2(Z,X);
ze      = x.^2 + y.^2; % define some condition
m       = 0.59; % manual input
cond    = (pi/3 <= alpha)     & ...
          (alpha <= (2*pi/3)) & ...
          (m <= Z)            & ...
          (Z <= ze); % more conditions 

xl = nnz(cond);        % the number of non-zero elements   
f  = abs(xl*1000 - 90) % guessing m to get f as low as possible
```

How do I turn `m` into a variable for some `f` function so I can call `fminsearch` to quickly find the corresponding `m` for `f ≈ 0`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `m` as a variable, you need to define a function handle. So you need to write:

```
 cond = @(m) ((pi/3) <= alpha) & (alpha <= (2*pi/3)) & (m <= Z) & (Z <= ze);
```

However, you cannot use a function handle in the `nnz` routine, since it only accepts matrices as inputs. But, the solution to the problem is that you only have Boolean variables in `cond`. This means, you can simply sum over `cond` and get the same result as with `nnz`.

The only issue I see is how to implement the sum in `fminsearch`. Unfortunately, I do not have access to `fminsearch`, however I would assume that you can do something with `reshape` and then multiply with dot (i.e. `.*`) with the unity vector to get a sum. But you'll have to try that one out, not sure about it.